# Two pip versions in one venv - how to remove one of them

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

I've got venv with two versions of pip installed, how to remove one of them? Venv uses 10.0.1 by default, but when I try to run

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I get:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\<username>\pycharmprojects\convertshapefile\venv\lib\site-packages (18.0)
```

ls from `<project>\venv\Lib\site-packages`:

```
Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       03.08.2018     14:36                pip
d-----       02.08.2018     16:58                pip-10.0.1-py3.7.egg
d-----       03.08.2018     14:36                pip-18.0.dist-info
d-----       02.08.2018     16:59                pyshp-1.2.12.dist-info
d-----       02.08.2018     16:59                __pycache__
-a----       03.08.2018     14:36             31 easy-install.pth
-a----       02.08.2018     16:58         563215 setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg
-a----       02.08.2018     16:58             31 setuptools.pth
-a----       02.08.2018     16:59          52285 shapefile.py
```

EDIT:

After I pip-10.0.1-py3.7.egg renamed to pip-10.0.1-py3.7.egg_xxx, I get

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\<username>\PycharmProjects\ConvertShapefile> pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<username>\PycharmProjects\ConvertShapefile\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 574, in _build_master
  File "C:\Users\<username>\PycharmProjects\ConvertShapefile\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 892, in require
  File "C:\Users\<username>\PycharmProjects\ConvertShapefile\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 783, in resolve
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 18.0 (c:\users\<username>\pycharmprojects\convertshapefile\venv\lib\site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==10.0.1'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<username>\PycharmProjects\ConvertShapefile\venv\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Users\<username>\PycharmProjects\ConvertShapefile\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3086, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\<username>\PycharmProjects\ConvertShapefile\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3070, in _call_aside
  File "C:\Users\<username>\PycharmProjects\ConvertShapefile\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3099, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "C:\Users\<username>\PycharmProjects\ConvertShapefile\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 576, in _build_master
  File "C:\Users\<username>\PycharmProjects\ConvertShapefile\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 589, in _build_from_requirements
  File "C:\Users\<username>\PycharmProjects\ConvertShapefile\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 778, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==10.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try renaming `pip-10.0.1-py3.7.egg` to, say, `pip-10.0.1-py3.7.egg_nope`.

If that makes your Python use 18.x, you can safely remove the now renamed .egg file.

Comment: Now I get exceptions about freezed versions of packages (I edited question for readibility)

Comment: Hmm. At this point I'd just suggest updating pip, setuptools, wheel, and virtualenv outside the virtualenv (i.e. update the global versions), then recreate the virtualenv. :-/